# Dynamically changing autocomplete source option jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this scenario I've got a textbox to which I have added autocomplete functionality.  The kicker is that I want to dynamically change the source option of the AJAX call based on the value of a dropdown list.  To do this I encapsulated the differences between the AJAX calls in an object of type `Resolver`. The `name` property of the Resolver object is the same as the text value coming from the dropdown list.  I was looking for a way to make this a little cleaner.  The code works, just looking for more extensible options as the project grows.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
    {
        //encapsulate the URL of the AJAX call
        //the name property maps to a dropdown list value
        //so if Drugs is chosen from the dropdown menu we look for the name property which = drugs
        Resolver = function (name, url)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.url = url;

        }
        Resolver.prototype.resolve = function (request, response)
        {
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "Service.asmx/" + this.url,
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'param': $('#auto').val() }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data)
                {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr)
                {
                    console.log(xhr.status);
                }
            });
        }
        //in the future I expect the Resolver object to have more properties
        //this is the simplest example I could think of
        var drugs = new Resolver('drugs', 'GetDrugNames');
        var hospitals = new Resolver('hospitals', 'GetHospitalNames');
        var resolverArray = [];
        resolverArray.push(drugs);
        resolverArray.push(hospitals);
        //on the change even of the ddl we're looking for the index of the resolverArray
        //which has the name name property as the value selected in the ddl.
        $('#ddl').change(function ()
        {
            var target = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
            var index = 0;
            $.each(resolverArray, function (ix, val)
            {
                if (resolverArray[ix].name == target)
                {
                    index = ix;
                }
            });
            $('#auto').autocomplete(
            {
                source: function (request, response)
                {
                    resolverArray[index].resolve(request, response);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: You needn't, and probably shouldn't, call `JSON.stringify` when passing an object as the `data` property to jQ's `$.ajax`, jQ will do that for you

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem how else will this work if the data property of the ajax call doesn't know what the name of the parameter in the web method is?

Comment: passing `{ param: $('#auto').val() }` to the data property will sent the `$('#auto').val()` value as `$_POST['param']`... the request will look like this: `param=<encodeURI($('#auto').val()>`, so no need to decode/parse the data

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I couldn't get `{ param: $('#auto').val() }` to work.  I'm using .NET 4.0 and get an `InvalidJsonPrimitive` error.

Comment: That's because jQ doesn't send its data as JSON by default, but defaults to the `x-www-form-urlencoded` mime

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem this happened even if I set the dataType property to json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to make it extensible is to make it reusable rather than stick it to one dropdown. You can even make it into a jQuery plugin so that it looks like this:

```
$('.someAutocompleteBox').dependentAutoComplete({

  /* the selector of the element to monitor changes */
  elementToMonitor : '.theElementToMonitor',

  /* value set, which correspond to the value of the previous input */
  sets : {
    drugs : DRUG_URL,
    hospitals : HOSPITAL_URL,
  }

  /* you can monitor depending on the event and which value to grab */
  triggeringEvent : 'keyup',
  propertyToCheck : 'value'
});
```

So in this example, I set `.someAutocompleteBox` to change sets when a `keyup` event is triggered from `.theElementToMonitor`. Then the plugin will grab the property defined in `propertyToCheck` and check it against the `sets` object which URL to use as source. Pretty simple isn't it?

As for jQuery plugin creation, you can use the [jQuery Boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate) to start off with a template. Everything else is self-explanatory, which is:

- In the `init()` function of your plugin code, attach an event stated by `triggeringEvent` to the element stated by `elementToMonitor`.
- When the event is fired, the handler should grab the value of the property defined in `propertyToCheck`.
- Do a lookup from the passed `sets` property and grab the URL of the corresponding key (which is the value grabbed from the property earlier)
- Update the current element's autocomplete source.

The plugin code (in the `init`) should look something like this:

```
init: function () {
  // nothing to check, nothing to check against
  if(!this.settings.elementToMonitor || !this.settings.sets) return;

  // Save the context
  var instance = this;

  // Attach the defined event to defined dependency
  $(this.settings.elementToMonitor)
    .on(this.settings.triggeringEvent,function(){

      // Get the value at defined property
      var value = $(this).prop(instance.settings.propertyToCheck);
      var url;

      // Check if we have that url in the set, return if not
      if(!(url = instance.set[value])) return;

      // Update the source accordingly
      $(instance.element).autocomplete({
        source = url;
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: I see several things I can use in here to improve upon.  Great stuff!